# Save dataframe to csv without NaN values, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) that I preprocessed with the following code:

```py
df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).agg(",".join).reset_index()

df = pd.concat([df, df['Col3'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)

cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)

df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

Which produced this dataframe:
[image: dataframe]

Then I exported it to `data.csv`:

```py
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

When I open `data.csv` in Notepad, it looks like this:
[image: csv output with many trailing commas after each row]

I don't want the trailing commas or empty values at the end of each row in the file.

This is what I want the CSV file to look like:
[image: desired csv output]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before you write your CSV file:

```py
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: But there are some rows with up to 11 items corresponding to these 11 columns as well. Hence, I cannot drop the entire columns. I just need the items and not all those extra commas in the end of the item list @user17242583

Comment: @d98p try my answer again. If it still doesn't work, we'll need to do something else, which _will_ work.